# Error when trying to exchange authorization code for access code using Google API

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am using the following C# code to try to get exchange my authorization code for an access code:

```
        const string TokenExchangeEndPointUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
        string data = string.Format(
              "code={0}&client_id={1}&client_secret={2}&redirect_url={3}&grant_type=authorization_code",
              (value), (_clientId), (_clientSecret), (RedirectUri));

        var utfenc = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] buffer = utfenc.GetBytes(data);
        var req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(TokenExchangeEndPointUrl);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

        using (Stream strm = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            strm.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            strm.Close();
        }
        var response = (HttpWebResponse) req.GetResponse();
```

The very last line is where the error is occurring. The error I'm getting is (400) Bad Request. It occurs on the last line. From the examples I've seen online, I appear to be doing it right. I've run the code through Fiddler2 and it appears to match what I'm getting from [Google's OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground), which makes this problem really weird. I've triple checked my ClientId and Client Secret. They are correct for my application. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually figured it out. I was putting "redirect_url". It should be "redirect_uri"